# How to automatically spin n-number of helm deployments from a single helm chart

Tags: kubernetes, rabbitmq, kubernetes-helm

I have a meta helm chart which wraps up several charts:

meta-helm-chart

```
.
|-- Chart.yaml
|-- README.md
|-- charts
|-- dashboards
|-- deployment.yaml
|-- templates
`-- values.yaml
```

I have like 6 sub-helm charts in the folder **charts/**.

```
tree charts/ -L 1
charts/
|-- chart-1
|-- chart-2
|-- chart-3
|-- chart-4
|-- prometheus-rabbitmq-exporter
`-- chart-6
```

When opening main **values.yaml**

```
...
...
rabbitmqTarget 10.20.30.40
...
```

In this fashion **prometheus-rabbitmq-exporter** helm chart will be deployed and RabbitMQ at IP address `10.20.30.40` will be scraped.

**What I am trying to do:**

I would like to have my **values.yaml**:

```
...
...
rabbitmqTarget [10.20.30.40, 50.60.70.80]
...
```

Unfortunately [RabbitMQ prometheus exporter] (https://github.com/kbudde/rabbitmq_exporter) can't scrape more targets.

Can anybody advise how to **schedule** as many deployments as specified in 
`rabbitmqTarget [10.20.30.40, 50.60.70.80]` ??? simply by using helm chart ?

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge there is no way to do this "simply by using helm". You would need some sort of wrapper / script to run multiple helm installs.

Comment: Hey, thx for the response, I do understand that by scripting these deployments I could go through however, that is not the option.

we went **from**:
wrappers + helm charts

**to**:
helm charts exclusively

Comment: so did you figure it out?

Comment: not at all, I think the only option is to have an exporter which would be able to monitor more rabbit instances, I have opened a github issue

Comment: Ah yes, I had a similar issue with the `github-exporter` for p8s recently. I ended up forking and fixing it myself.